# Selecting an item in a Dropdown control from javascript no jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Office UI Fabric and I'm using a ms-Dropdown control.
From javascript, I'm trying to select and item

```
<div class="ms-Dropdown" tabindex="0">
  <label class="ms-Label" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">My Options</label>
  <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i>
  <select id="myoptions" class="ms-Dropdown-select">
    <option>Choose an option&amp;hellip;</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

From Javascript, I run

```
document.getElementById("myoptions").value = "Two";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myoptions").selectedIndex = 2;
```

Both don't work properly. The UI don't refresh with the new selected option.

Any idea how can I select an item from Javascript (no jQuery)?

Comment: `document.getElementById("myoptions").selectedIndex = 2;` should work!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your options are missing values:

```
 <select id="myoptions" class="ms-Dropdown-select">
    <option value=''>Choose an option&amp;hellip;</option>
    <option value='One'>One</option>
    <option value='Two'>Two</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myoptions").selectedIndex = 2;` should work!!!

Comment: But UI is not updated with the selected value. The first option is showed, not updated with new selected option.

Answer (score 1):

Use this solution :

```js
 //set item index
 var option = document.getElementById("myoptions").item(2)
 option.setAttribute("selected",true)
```

```html
   <div class="ms-Dropdown" tabindex="0">
  <label class="ms-Label" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 600;">My Options</label>
  <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown"></i>
  <select id="myoptions" class="ms-Dropdown-select">
    <option>Choose an option&amp;hellip;</option>
    <option >One</option>
    <option >Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("myoptions").options.selectedIndex = 2;
```